# nontrivial system of ODE in a vector form

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of kinetic balance rate equations in the following form

$\frac{db_{j}}{dt}=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}R_{ji}(b_{j}-b_{i})$. The initial conditions are $b_{2}(t=0)=1$ and $b_{i}(t=0)=0$ for all $ i\neq2$, $R_{ji}$ ($i,j=1,N$) is the matrix of real and defined coefficients and $N$ is a given size of system. Solution should be in the interval $\left[0,\infty\right]$. How to write this in Mathematica in a general form with the use matrices R and b? The main problem that $i$ and $j$ are the subsest of other "quantun numbers". For instence i could be $i=\left(2,0,1\right)e$ or $i=\left(1,0,0\right)$ and etc. (3 integer numbers define these $i$ and $j$)

It should be something like this: DSolve[{eqn1,eqn2,...,condition1,condition2,....},{b1,b2,...},{t,0,Infinity}]

The example of $R$-matrix is here (txt file) https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuwhlsieyvg8nf9/example.txt?dl=0

Comment: What's the range of $j$? Can you supply an example of $R$?

Comment: $R_{ij}$ is the matrix $N\times N$, i.e. $i,j=1,N$

Comment: Do you need a symbolic solution (DSolve) or would a numerical solution (NDSolve) suffice?

Comment: its better to find symbolic solution.This system can be solved symbolic

Comment: May I suggest explaining a bit on how the numbers in that file should be interpreted? Consider e.g. the numbers in the first line `1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1.7989e+09`: that last number is too large to be a "probability". And you still haven't explained how these numbers map to a matrix.

Comment: The last number is the transition rate (or decay 'probability') in inverse seconds. Usually atomic level has a lifetime $\frac{1}{\Gamma}$ $s$ where $\Gamma \approx 10^{8}$ $s^{-1}$. This $\Gamma$ or $Rji$ is given in the last column, 1,0,0 is set of quantum numbers (principal quantum number, spin and angular momentum of a state $i=1^1S$ (atomic notation)), 2,0,1 is other set of quantum numbers for state  $j=2^1P$. So the transition rate (rate is more correct abbreviation than probability) for transition 2,0,1-> 1,0,0 is 1.7989e+09 $s^{-1}$.

Comment: Maybe it would be quicker if you can point to a textbook or paper that discusses this example. I appreciate your giving the physical interpretations (you should edit your question to put those in), but that gives no indication on how `1.7989e+09` goes into, say, the $(1,1)$ entry of $\mathbf R$ (or whatever position it's supposed to be in in that matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Your system of ODEs can be expressed as

$\mathbf b^\prime(t)=\mathbf S\mathbf b(t)$

where $\mathbf S$ is derived from your matrix $\mathbf R$. Here is a routine to produce $\mathbf S$:

```
makeCoefficientMatrix[R_?SquareMatrixQ] := R - DiagonalMatrix[Total[R, {2}]]
```

From this, you can now use `DSolve[]` or `NDSolve[]` for your ODEs.

Letting, for example,

```
r = 1/Array[Max, {4, 4}];
```

here is how to use `NDSolveValue[]`:

```
vf = NDSolveValue[{v'[t] == makeCoefficientMatrix[r].v[t],
                   v[0] == UnitVector[Length[r], 2]}, v, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Plot the solutions:

```
Plot[Table[Indexed[vf[t], k], {k, 4}] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: solutions]

---

To solve symbolically, we can use `DSolve[]`, but then we recall that `MatrixExp[]` can be used instead for constant-coefficient first order equations:

```
MatrixExp[makeCoefficientMatrix[r] t, UnitVector[4, 2]]
   {1/4 - 1/2 E^(-19 t/12) + 1/6 E^(-5 t/4) + E^-t/12, 
    1/4 + 1/2 E^(-19 t/12) + 1/6 E^(-5 t/4) + E^-t/12, 
    1/4 - 1/3 E^(-5 t/4) + E^-t/12, 1/4 - E^-t/4}
```

`Plot[MatrixExp[makeCoefficientMatrix[r] t, UnitVector[4, 2]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]` should produce the same picture.

Comment: The most intriguing problem that $R_{ij}$ is complicated matrix since $i$  and $j$ are the sets of other numbers. For instance R[i,j]=R[2,0,1,1,0,0]=1.78E+9 where i={2,0,1} and j={1,0,0}. There ae other nonzero sets , for example R[4,0,2,2,0,1, R[2,0,2,2,0,1] and etc.

Comment: Why didn't you include that information in your question?

Comment: I simplified the task, since its related to the atomic physics, i={2,0,1} corresponds to $2^1P$ state in helium atom. So i nd j can be defined only by a subset of numbers.

Comment: As long as your $\mathbf R$ is a constant matrix, and does not depend on $t$, the solution here will work.

Comment: The question is how to define matrix R[nj,sj,lj,  ni,si,li]? Each i or j is 3-integer-component vector.

Comment: Do you have a textbook or paper describing the method to generate $\mathbf R$?

Comment: Here is the dat file for R matrix https://www.dropbox.com/s/tj6ddhwu3xnayc3/example.dat?dl=0 or txt version https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuwhlsieyvg8nf9/example.txt?dl=0

Comment: Please edit your question to include that link instead of leaving it in a comment.

Comment: I also made an example for $N=2$ i.e. $2\times2$ system: an = DSolve[{D[b[2, 0, 1, t],  t] == -(R[2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ] (b[2, 0, 1, t] - b[1, 0, 0, t])),    D[b[1, 0, 0, t], t] == -(R[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, ] (b[1, 0, 0, t] - b[2, 0, 1, t])),    b[2, 0, 1, 0] == 1, b[1, 0, 0, 0] == 0}, {b[2, 0, 1, t], 
   b[1, 0, 0, t]}, {t, 0, Infinity}]. This gives a symbolic solution.